# retrieve variable name in iterator

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, iteration

I have a very basic class in C# and I've implemented an iterator to cycle all its  string values (variables), here is the `foreach` code:

```
string strList = "";
foreach (string param in vars) 
{
    strList += param + "\r\n";
}
```

now this is cool, my class `vars` contains several `public string ...` and it cycles the values correctly, however I also want to save in my `strList` what value is being printed in a line, hence the respectove `vars` variable name.

Comment: you might want to provide the provide the more complete code, and then some examples of values you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: @sstan there are multiple `public string ...` inside the class from which is instantiated my `vars` so for example you have `public string first_name` as also `public string phone_number` so I want to print that value and not just each variable content, example: `first_name: Mike` and so on.

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you actually posted your class `vars` so we can also see how the iterator is implemented.  It will make everything clearer that much quicker.

Comment: It's all in the `GetEnumerator()` method of your `vars` class, which you have not yet shared with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the workaround that I've found so far, not really the solution that I'm looking for, so I'm open for more correct answers than mine. In my class iterator implementation, I return the values like this:

```
yield return first_name; yield return phone_number; ...
```

a very simple "solution" is to pass the variable name along with the value inside the iterator, however should I need to iterate the values I'll have to split and filter the result, thats why I say I preferred a more clean solution:

```
yield return "first_name: " + first_name; 
yield return "phone_number: " + phone_number; 
...
```